# Font ligature icons in Microsoft edge

Tags: html, fonts, microsoft-edge, ligature

I'm using google material Icon font library for the majority of icons in a web app. I've started debugging for Microsoft Edge and realised none of them are showing.

Is this a known issue? I can switch to actual icon images if need be but it would be a massive job at this stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use F12 developer tools to check whether the Google Icons CSS reference load success.

The following code works well on Edge 42 and Edge 44 version:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Material Icons';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        src: url(https://example.com/MaterialIcons-Regular.eot); /* For IE6-8 */
        src: local('Material Icons'), local('MaterialIcons-Regular'), url(https://example.com/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2) format('woff2'), url(https://example.com/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff) format('woff'), url(https://example.com/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
    }

    .material-icons {
        font-family: 'Material Icons';
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        font-size: 24px; /* Preferred icon size */
        display: inline-block;
        line-height: 1;
        text-transform: none;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        word-wrap: normal;
        white-space: nowrap;
        direction: ltr;
        /* Support for all WebKit browsers. */
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        /* Support for Safari and Chrome. */
        text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
        /* Support for Firefox. */
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        /* Support for IE. */
        font-feature-settings: 'liga';
    }
</style>
<i class="material-icons">face</i>
```

The output screenshot as below:

[image]